# maven compile fails

Tags: java, maven-2

I have encountered the following error. Can anyone give any solution?

**Build errors for CTServices; org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project CTServices: Compilation failure**

Comment: Looks like your Java code doesn't compile. You need to provide more Maven output though!

Comment: check whether your code java version corresponds to one in pom, maven-compiler-plugin and some more stacktrace would be useful

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is some problem with your code or some dependency might be missing, causing java code compilation failure. Try mvn -e option to get the detail stack trace that might be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try with -X option and provide the output if you still have the issue